# Check a specific variable has value or not in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to check a variable value before a div so that if variable is empty then hide the div that is in if condition and vice versa.

e.g:

```
<?php $var=has_post_thumbnail();
if(!empty($var)){ ?>
<div>//some code that is shown only if var has some value</div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: so wat's the problem...?

Comment: actually i stored a video url in a variable against a post and i want to check that if video has stored in that variable then the followed div (in which this variable is echoed) is shown otherwise the div (in which video is echoed) should remain hiden

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if(isset($var)) // or check for empty if you want that way{ ?>
    <div> yes variable is set </div>
<?php } else { ?>
    <div> variable not set division </div>
<?php } ?>
```